# User cannot receive confirmation mail on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I've set up my blog and everything except for one thing works correct.
When users try to register they can and are added to the database but they never get their password emailed?
Anyone has a solution for this?
Oh btw: I myself am getting email notifications from wordpress-blog, so the mail() function and probably the sendmail() function are working..

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a third party theme? I had a problem recently where users who registered were not receiving an email. I was using a third party theme that had a custom login/register box. When I tried using the registration box built into the WP theme, emails went out. Might be worth a try. Just add the 'stock' box to a sidebar.